# Heroku: Creating a simple, static one page website on Cedar

Tags: heroku, cedar

I'm attempting to upload a simple one page web page using Heroku.

I was previously using the Play! Framework but it seems overkill for a single page with some javascript.

```
+ project/
 + public/
  + css/
   ...
  + img/
   ...
  + js/
   ...
 index.html
```

How do I upload a basic set of static files to Heroku? There seems to be no documentation on their website on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the purpose of Heroku to host static websites. However, you still can do it but you have to create either a Ruby on Rails, Play, etc. project, add the HTML in the folders.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku doesn't really support static web pages, it supports Apps. However, a static web page can trivially be 'enhanced' to be a PHP application by adding a dummy index.php.

So if you want to host a file foo.html as a Heroku app Foo, then:
1. Create Foo on Heroku.
2. [Clone empty repository to local directory] git clone git@heroku.com:Foo.git -o heroku
3. touch index.php
4. [add foo.html]
5. git add .
6. git commit -m 'test'
7. git push heroku master

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has a guide to doing this with Rack: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby

Basically, create a simple Rack app with a `config.ru` file:

```
use Rack::Static,
  :urls => ["/images", "/js", "/css"],
  :root => "public"

run lambda { |env|
  [
    200,
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html',
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400'
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
```

a `Gemfile`:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'rack'
```

and a public folder with an `index.html` file and folders for other assets, structured like this:

```
my_site/config.ru
my_site/Gemfile
my_site/public/index.html
my_site/public/css
my_site/public/images
my_site/public/js
```

And someone has made a site that will generate all the necessary files for you: http://herokustaticmagico.herokuapp.com/